# checking for active timer (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript

I have a function that contain setTimeout() Method.

I have a button that calls that function, so you could hit this button multiple times and call this function as many times as you want.

Is there a way to actually execute this function, only if there is no other instance of this function that has an active timer?

Comment: Show us the code, you obviously have something for the event handler and the timeout already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to keep track of whether you had previously set this timer or not and whether it was still active by using some sort of variable that had a scope that persisted across multiple button presses.

There is no built-in function that will tell you whether the timer you started with this button is still running.  You have to create your own.  It could work something like this:

```
var buttonTimer;
function myButtonClick() {
    if (!buttonTimer) {
        buttonTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            buttonTimer = null;
            // put your timer code here
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

This will ignore the button click as long as there is a currently active timer.  When there is no timer running, it will set a new timer.

Because you're keeping track of the actual timer ID, you have the freedom to implement other behaviors too such as cancelling the previous timer (such as a stop button) or reset the timer to a new time interval by cancelling the previous timer and then setting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Timer = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.running = false;
    this.run = function() {
        if(!self.running) {
            self.running = true;
            console.log('starting run');
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.running = false;
                console.log('done running!');
            }, 5000);
        } else {
         console.log('i was running already!');   
        }
    }
    return this;
}
var aTimer = new Timer();
```

And add a button for testing purposes:

```
<button onclick="aTimer.run()">Run!</button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kukiwon/FCuNh/